# How can i create a graph using springy js in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, graph, springy.js

hi i am using springy js for creating a graph

my code is

```
<script>
        var graph = new Springy.Graph();

        <%=define_variable%>;
        <%=define_depandencey%>;

        jQuery(function(){
          var springy = window.springy = jQuery('#springydemo').springy({
            graph: graph,
            nodeSelected: function(node){
              console.log('Node selected: ' + JSON.stringify(node.data));
            }
          });
        });
    </script>
```

and i am getting the result like 
[image]

but my need is that all nodes have a sequence and it must connects in sequence in the graph like the below image

[image]

So could you please help to create it by using springy js or any other way to create it.

Comment: share the sample data for `<%=define_variable%>;
        <%=define_depandencey%>;`

Comment: variable one node is:    var TD1 = graph.newNode({label: 'TD1'})                       and its depandencey is :          graph.newEdge(TD1,hidTD2, {color: '#00A0B0'});graph.newEdge(TD1, TD2a1, {color: '#00A0B0'});graph.newEdge(TD1, TD4a, {color: '#00A0B0'});graph.newEdge(TD1, TD4b, {color: '#00A0B0'});graph.newEdge(TD1, PipeTD4a_global, {color: '#00A0B0'});graph.newEdge(TD1, TD8_global, {color: '#00A0B0'});graph.newEdge(TD1, TD2, {color: '#00A0B0'});graph.newEdge(TD1, TD12_global, {color: '#00A0B0'});graph.newEdge(TD1, TD10_global, {color: '#00A0B0'});